# Can I use pm2 instead loadbalancer?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing, pm2

I have an application running in the Elastic BeanStalk on AWS, can I install pm2 to manage my aplication and turn off the loadbalancer, is better have only the loadbalancer or have two at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PM2 according it's [documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/) is daemon process manager that will help you manage and keep your application online. It is not built for load balance.

For balance traffic between [cluster of services](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/) you should to use separate load balancing solution like [haproxy](http://www.haproxy.org/) or other solution

Comment: According to its doc it has a builtin load balancer. What is this compared to haproxy or nginx then? https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/guide/load-balancing/